# Proof involving Transpose of Matrix: If $P^T=P^T P$ then $P=P^T=P^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $P^T=P^T P$ then why $P=P^T=P^2$. Only a hint is enough to solve this which looks like an algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the transpose of both sides of the equation $P^T = P^TP$.

Comment: understood, thanks